# Not able to pass with using input attribution

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Codes in JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qs9jq/1/).

The following codes are supposed to pass when you add message and submit. But I always get pop-up, "Please fill all fields!". What am I doing wrong here?

HTML

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="admin/insertShoutBox" >
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="user" id="nick" value="admin" />
    <p class="messagelabel"><label class="messagelabel">Message</label>
        <textarea  id="message" name="message" rows="2" cols="80"></textarea>
    </p>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button type="submit" class="positive" name="submit" value="submit">
        <img src="http://localhost/kaimonokago3/assets/icons/disk.png" alt="disk"/>            Save            </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//global vars
var inputUser = $("#nick");
var inputMessage = $("#message");

//check if all fields are filled
function checkForm()
{
    if(inputUser.attr("value") && inputMessage.attr("value"))
    {
        return true;
    }   
    else
    {
        return false;
    }      
}


//on submit event
$("#form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(checkForm())
    {
        // doing something here
    }
    else alert("Please fill all fields!");
    //we prevent the refresh of the page after submitting the form
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: CheckForm() function check only that input has attribute Value or not. You are not checking any validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to read the value not the value attribute, when you enter data the attribute value is not updated instead value property is updated

```
function checkForm()
{
    if(inputUser.val() && inputMessage.val())
    {
        return true;
    }   
    else
    {
        return false;
    }      
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EeX5Z/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the value of your `input`, not attribute, you can use **[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** to get the value of your `input`, so you can do:

```
if($.trim(inputUser.val()) && $.trim(inputMessage.val())) {
```

or:

```
if($.trim(inputUser.val()) != ''  && $.trim(inputMessage.val()) != '') {
```

instead of:

```
if(inputUser.attr("value") && inputMessage.attr("value")) {
```

Please note that you need to use **[$.trim()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)** to remove all white space to prevent users from submitting form when they only key in the white space inside the input.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EeX5Z/3/)**

Comment: If you are using `inputuser.val()!='' `, you'd be better of using `$.trim(inputuser.val())!='' ` instead

Answer (score 0):

Use `inputMessage.val()` instead of `inputMessage.attr("value")`
Check out [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) usage.

Reason : 
Check out the difference between attributes and properties [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).
When you input some text in text area, the property is updated rather than the attribute.

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sh83k/)

Also, a better way to check would be :

```
function checkForm()
{
    return CheckStringInput(inputUser.val()) && CheckStringInput(inputMessage.val());      
}

function CheckStringInput(stringInput){
   if(typeof stringInput!="undefined" && stringInput!=null && $.trim(stringInput)!='')
      return true;
   return false;
}
```